# Как сделать ajax выборку из БД по нескольким параметрам?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, выборка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую ajax выборку?

Табы сделал, а вот как дальше по кнопке продолжить выборку?

Получается при нажатии на таб у меня получается `?tab=1`

Дальше при нажатии на кнопку 1, 2 и т.д. я должен получить `?tab=1&sub=11`

Не могу понять, что в пхп и ajax надо написать? И пример не могу найти.

```
<div id="ajax-reload">
    <div class='tab'>
        <div class='tab-header'>
          <div class='tab' data-tab='1'>Таб 1</div>
          <div class='tab' data-tab='2'>Таб 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class='tab-content'>
            <div class='subs'>
                <div class='sub' data-sub='11'>Кнопка 1</div>
                <div class='sub' data-sub='22'>Кнопка 2</div>
                <div class='sub' data-sub='33'>Кнопка 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class='subs-content'>
                <div class='item'>Текст 1</div>
                <div class='item'>Текст 2</div>
                <div class='item'>Текст 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
            $('.tab').on('click', function() {
                var $data_tab;
                $data_tab = $(this).attr('data-tab');
                $.get("URL_PAGE", {
                        tab: $data_tab
                    })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $("#ajax-reload").html(data);
                    });
            });
        });

$tab = $_GET['tab'];
    //Подгружаем объекты по нажатию на таб
    if(isset($tab)){
        $query_where = "Sub_ID=$tab";
    }
```

Comment: Для взаимодействия с базой, вам нужно написать php-функцию, которая будет делать выборку из базы по нужному параметру, дальше эти данные нужно отдавать в формате json, после получения данных в JS их нужно парсить и формировать html-код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
            $('.tab').on('click', function() {
                location.href = '?tab=' + $(this).attr('data-tab');
            });

            $('.sub').on('click', function() {
                location.href = '?<?=($_GET[tab] ? "tab=$tab_slc"."&" : NULL);?>sub=' + $(this).attr('data-sub');
            });
        });



$tab_slc = $_GET['tab'];
    $sub_slc = $_GET['sub']; 

    if($tab_slc OR $sub_slc) 
    { 
        if($tab_slc)
        {
            $query_where_array[] = "Parent=$tab_slc";
        }
        if($sub_slc) {
            $query_where_array[] = "Services=$sub_slc";
        }
        $query_where = implode(" && ", $query_where_array);
    }
```

Осталось дело за ajax'ом

Answer (score 1):

> Дальше при нажатии на кнопку 1, 2 и т.д. я должен получить `?tab=1&sub=11`.
>
> Не могу понять, что в пхп и ajax надо написать?

Проще всего для вкладки *.sub* добавить `data-tab`, после чего Вам станет очень просто получать `tab` и `sub`.
В вашем же случае, если предположить, что при нажатии на `tab`, ему добавляется класс `active`(или иной другой, который добавляет стиль активной вкладки), получаем следующее:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".sub", function() {
  var sub = $(this).data("sub");
  var tab = $(".tab.active").data("tab");
  console.log("?tab=" + tab + "&sub=" + sub);
});
```

```css
.tab-content {
  width: 618px;
}
.tab-content,
.tab-header .tab,
.sub,
.item {
  border: 2px solid #EE497A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tab.active {
  background: #2D4565;
  color: #fff;
}
.tab-header .tab,
.sub {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-header .tab,
.sub,
.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item {
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ajax-reload">
  <div class='tab'>
    <div class='tab-header'>
      <div class='tab active' data-tab='1'>Таб 1</div>
      <div class='tab' data-tab='2'>Таб 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tab-content'>
      <div class='subs'>
        <div class='sub' data-sub='11'>Кнопка 1</div>
        <div class='sub' data-sub='22'>Кнопка 2</div>
        <div class='sub' data-sub='33'>Кнопка 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='subs-content'>
        <div class='item'>Текст 1</div>
        <div class='item'>Текст 2</div>
        <div class='item'>Текст 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S.: если же вдруг по какой-то причине Вы  не добавляете для активной вкладки *.tab* класс `active` или любой другой, получите активную вкладку при помощи [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Немного не то, но спасибо. Идею понял.